# Is it possible to add an offset of text to the UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a book app. User choose a book and UITextView show it. Every book has a caption. I need to add 55px offset to the top of UITextView. I want that every caption has 55px offset. But I don't know how to do this?

1)My text height is 22px. I can add 2 or 3 empty line of text, but it doesn't suit me because I need 55px.
2)I can add contentOffset.y = 55. But I have a problem. contentOffset will be zero if an user scroll to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `contentInset` in `UIScrollView`?

`textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(55.0, 0, 0, 0);`